# -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] crashes with no error in console

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller

**Update**

I swapped out completely different code for pushViewController, and it is still crashing... seems like pushViewController is not the culprit. Here is what I added instead:

```
NSString *videoURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.vimeo.com/m/#/%@", videoID];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
```

It opens up the URL in Safari, and then crashes.. wtf?

---

PushViewController crashes with no error in the console, but I do get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in Xcode. The crash doesn't happen until after the view controller has been pushed... but the view its pushing is empty... no code to mess up.

My code is below:

MainViewController.m

```
PlayVimeo *playTest = [[PlayVimeo alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayVimeo" bundle:nil];
    //playTest.videoID = videoID;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:playTest animated:YES];
    [playTest release];
```

PlayVimeo.m

```
#import "PlayVimeo.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"


@implementation PlayVimeo
@synthesize videoID, wView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Show loading alert
    [SVProgressHUD showInView:self.view status:@"Loading Video..."];
    }


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {     

    NSLog(@"Play View Loaded!");

    [self vimeoVideo];
    }


-(void)vimeoVideo {

    NSLog(@"Video ID: %@", videoID);

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>"
                      @"<head>"
                      @"<meta name = \"viewport\" content =\"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 460\"/></head>"
                      @"<frameset border=\"0\">"
                      @"<frame src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=1&amp;autoplay=1\" width=\"460\" height=\"320\" frameborder=\"0\"></frame>"
                      @"</frameset>"
                      @"</html>", 
                      videoID];

    NSLog(@"HTML String: %@", html);

    [wView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    //Dismiss loading alert
    [SVProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"Playing..."];
    }



- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    }
```

Navigation Controller Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [Appirater appLaunched];

    return YES;
    }
```

Console on crash:

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Comment: Your navigationcontroller is correctly allocated and initialized with a rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Post your code! It's impossible to tell what's happening without a backtrace.

Comment: Yes... the crash doesn't happen until after the view controller has been pushed...

Comment: try not to release the 'playTest' See whether its  crashing or not..

Comment: You still haven't shown how you create your navigationcontroller.

Comment: I added my navigationcontroller code above.

Comment: There should be a problem in dealloc in the class from where you called pushViewController.

Comment: I checked my dealloc... everything matches up with the header file. Arrrrgh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the culprit is

```
[playTest release];
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I would still say that you likely need to release this after you're done with the video.

Comment: I removed the pushviewcontroller code and replaced it to open a URL in safari (outside the application)... it still crashes... `playTest` doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code can not be fixed, it seems. With the UIWebView class reference, there is an example program `TransWeb`. Take this as base, it has a window and a navigation controller with a webview in it (in the xib). In  `MyViewController` it reads a html-file and displays it. What you need to do is to change the main view to landscape and replace the html-code with yours. Avoid the frame-stuff.

Comment: I don't think it's the webView... I removed all webView code and replaced it with open outside URL code in Safari... still crashes.